# Counting Getters and Setters

Tags: java

I am working on a project that requires to count the number of getters and setters in a compiled java code. I am new to this and dont know where and how to start.
 I have installed eclipse and added the Bytecode plugin to see the bytecode of the java code.

Any thoughts on what i need to do next?

Comment: How `Java` and `Assembly` tags related here?

Comment: You'll want to use reflection. What have you tried?

Comment: +1 for the use of reflection.

Comment: You have to decide what a getter is. Do your classes follow the java bean conventions?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `java.lang.reflect.*` package to get all the class info such as variable, methods, constructors and inner classes.

Example:

```
public int noOfGettersOf(Class clazz) {
    int noOfGetters = 0;
    Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods()
    for(Method method : methods) {
        String methodName = method.getName();
        if(methodName.startsWith("get") || methodName.startsWith("is")) {
            noOfGetters++;
        }
    }
    return noOfGetters;
}
```

Follow the same approach for setters, one thing you need to consider is boolean getters they usually starts with `is` instead of `get`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Class.getDeclaredMethods()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%290), with something like this

```
public static int countGets(Class<?> cls) {
  int c = 0;
  for (java.lang.reflect.Method m : cls.getMethods()) {
    if (m.getName().startsWith("get")) {
      c++;
    }
  }
  return c;
}

public static int countSets(Class<?> cls) {
  int c = 0;
  for (java.lang.reflect.Method m : cls.getMethods()) {
    if (m.getName().startsWith("set")) {
      c++;
    }
  }
  return c;
}
```

Comment: What about using ASM to count getfield/putfield instructions, is that possible?

Comment: What are you asking? [Jasmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasmin_%28Java_assembler%29)?

Answer (score 3):

Refer the Apache byte code manipulation library [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/).
The Byte Code Engineering Library  is intended to give users a convenient way to analyze, create, and manipulate (binary) Java class files (those ending with .class).

After that you can use reflection to get the count like this :

```
public static int getGetterMethodCount(Class<?> cls) {
    int n = 0;
    for (Method m : cls.getMethods()) {
        // To identify the boolean setter "is" is used
        if (m.getName().startsWith("get") || m.getName().startsWith("is")) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

public static int getSetterMethodCount(Class<?> cls) {
    int n = 0;
    for (Method m : cls.getMethods()) {
        if (m.getName().startsWith("set")) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```